# URI::InvalidURIError When Using HTTParty

Tags: ruby, sinatra, httparty

I followed an example from the [HTTParty github page](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and came up with this:

```
class MatchHistory
    include HTTParty
    base_uri = "api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570"

    def initialize
        @options = { query: { key: STEAM_API_KEY } }
    end

    def latest
        self.class.get("/GetMatchHistory/V001", @options)
    end
end

get '/' do 
    history = MatchHistory.new

    history.latest.body
end
```

I get the following error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError at /
the scheme http does not accept registry part: :80 (or bad hostname?)
```

However, when I use a simpler solution like the following, it returns the results just fine:

```
class MatchHistory
    def initialize
        @base_uri = "http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570"
    end

    def latest
        HTTParty.get(@base_uri + "/GetMatchHistory/V001/?key=" + STEAM_API_KEY)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base_uri` is a class method, so you should define it inside a class, not in your initializer. You can see it in the first example in a link you provided.

```
class MatchHistory
    include HTTParty

    base_uri "api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570"

    def initialize
        @options = { query: { key: STEAM_API_KEY } }
    end

    def latest
        self.class.get("/GetMatchHistory/V001", @options)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I've edited the question, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: equal sign is unnecessary too

Comment: Thanks! I somehow thought base_uri was a vairable rather than a method because of the lack of parentheses. Just carelessness on my part.